# How to compare two counters using TeX conditionals in ConTeXt?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, context, counters

I have two counters, `\definenumber[words]` and `\definenumber[items]`. I have tried to use TeX conditionals to compare them, e.g.:

```
\ifnum\getnumber[words]=\getnumber[items]
    This will print some text if the two counters have the same value.
fi
```

This does not work. How can I use TeX conditionals to compare two counters in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\definenumber` is a synonym for `\definestructurecounter`. You can use the expandable version `\rawstructurecountervalue` to get the value of the structure counter and use them in TeX conditionals.

An alternative is to use the `commands.doifelse(...)` lua function to do the comparison.
I present both versions below (using named arguments so that the macro is easy to understand. Either save this in a file with an extension `.mkvi` or use `% macros=mkvi` on the first line of the `.tex` file).

```
% macros=mkvi

\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\strc_helper_compare#if#else#operator#counterA#counterB%
    {\ctxcommand{doifelse(\rawstructurecountervalue[#counterA] #operator \rawstructurecountervalue[#counterB])}
        {#if}{#else}}

\unexpanded\def\doifelsecomparestructurecounter 
    {\strc_helper_compare\firstoftwoarguments\secondoftwoarguments}

\unexpanded\def\doifcomparestructurecounter 
    {\strc_helper_compare\firstofoneargument\gobbleoneargument}
\protect

\definestructurecounter[one]
\definestructurecounter[two]

\setstructurecounter[one][1]
\setstructurecounter[two][2]

\starttext
\ifnum\rawstructurecountervalue[one]>\rawstructurecountervalue[two]\relax
  One is bigger
\else
  Two is bigger
\fi

\doifelsecomparestructurecounter{>=}{one}{two}{Counter one is bigger}{Counter two is bigger}
\doifelsecomparestructurecounter{<}{one}{two}{Counter one is smaller}{Counter two is smaller}
\doifcomparestructurecounter{<}{one}{two}{Counter one is smaller}
\doifcomparestructurecounter{>}{one}{two}{Counter two is smaller}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Is there any other way to codify a numeric inequality conditional that's less abstruse? Why doesn't `\ifnum\rawcountervalue[MyCounter]>0` work, for example? Could it be made to work without everyone adding their own `unprotected`/`unexpanded` macros to accomplish the same task?

Comment: Does `\definestructurecounter` exist anymore?