# How to obtain the current page number in ConTeXt?

Tags: page-numbering, context, context-mkiv

I want to obtain the current page number, for use in Lua conditionals, e.g.:

```
\startlua
    if 10 <= \pagenumber < 20 then
        context("The pages are between 10 and 20")
    end
\stoplua
```

- According to this article on [counters](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Counters) at the ConTeXt wiki, I think `\getnumber[page]` should display the page number in a document, but it does not display anything.
- I thought [How to compare two counters using TeX conditionals in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51135/how-to-compare-two-counters-using-tex-conditionals-in-context) would provide the answers, but `\rawstructurecountervalue` seems to be undefined in my version of ConTeXt.

How can I display and work with the current page number in ConTeXt?

Comment: If you are using ConTeXt MkIV, you should use the latest version of the [ConTeXt Standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the current page number with `tex.count.pageno`.

```
\startluacode
    if 10 <= tex.count.pageno and tex.count.pageno < 20 then
        context("The pages are between 10 and 20")
    end
\stopluacode
```

Another thing: You have to combine the two tests with an `and`. A simple concatenation like in your example does not work.