# Where to find a list of all system-defined counters in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, counters, context-mkiv

I learned from [How to obtain the current page number in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/how-to-obtain-the-current-page-number-in-context) that I can obtain the page number counter value using `tex.count.pageno`, but I have not found this mentioned in any available documentation. I wonder, what other counters are available? Is there some place which has a complete list?

Comment: As Taco said, there is no such list, but you could start a page on the context wiki and others could add to the list over time.

Comment: Is that what the small list is at the end of http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Counters? If so, I will try to add what new ones I discover to the end of that page.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be a good place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The snippet `tex.count.pageno` is just luatex's representation of `\pageno`, which is more obvious when you realize that it is shorthand for `tex.count["pageno"]`. All of the `\newcount`-defined counters are accessible from lua that way, as well as anonymous counters by using `tex.count[0]`, and that is in no way ConTeXt-specific.

There is no published list of `\newcount` defined counters in ConTeXt. You can grep the ConTeXt source for `\newcount`, but most of the counters are for internal use only and of no interest to normal users. `\pageno` is a bit of an exception because it is in use in plain TeX and inherited from there.

The more interesting counters in ConTeXt are defined using `\definecounter`,
and these can be listed using code like this:

```
\startlua
table.print(structures.counters.data)
\stoplua
```

The counters associated with sectioning levels do not live there ,and I do not know where those are. Hopefully someone else will know.