# How can I test the value of two counters?

Tags: conditionals, counters

I'd like to test the value of counters (preferably as vanilla TeX as it gets).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterA}{2}
\setcounter{counterB}{2}

\newcommand\maccommand{
  \ifx\the\value{counterA}=\the\value{counterB} 
    Just so you know, counterA (= \the\value{counterA}) holds the same value as counterB (= \the\value{counterB}).
  \else 
    Sorry, but the counterA (= \the\value{counterA}) is not equal to counterB (= \the\value{counterB}).
  \fi
```

Yet in TeX you can write:

```
\ifx\counterA>2 
  Just so you know, counterA is greater to than 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
\fi
}
```

Why can't you write

```
\ifx\counterA=2 
  Just so you know, counterA is equal to 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not equal to 2.
\fi
}
```

OR

```
\ifx\counterA=\counterB 
  Just so you know, counterA is equal to counterB.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not equal to counterB.
\fi
}
```

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51135

Comment: not remarking on the tex code, but the logic -- if `\counterA=2` then it's absurd to report that "counterA is greater than 2."  (this is such a non sequitur that it's distracting me from the question itself ... i get distracted easily.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Haha, very true! I copied the code from the last block without thinking about the text. Fixed :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\thecounterA` works only if the counter wasn't redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterA}\renewcommand\thecounterA{A\arabic{counterA}}
\newcounter{counterB}\renewcommand\thecounterB{B\arabic{counterB}}
\setcounter{counterA}{2}
\setcounter{counterB}{2}

\newcommand\maccommand{%
  \ifnum\value{counterA}=\value{counterB}
    Just so you know, counterA (= \thecounterA) holds the same value as 
    counterB (=\thecounterB).%
  \else 
    Sorry, but the counterA (= \thecounterA) is not equal to counterB 
    (=\thecounterB).%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\maccommand

\stepcounter{counterA}
\maccommand

\end{document}
```

The TeX way:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\maccommand{%
  \ifnum\c@counterA=\c@counterB
    Just so you know, counterA (= \thecounterA) holds the same value as 
    counterB (=\thecounterB).%
  \else 
    Sorry, but the counterA (= \thecounterA) is not equal to counterB 
    (=\thecounterB).%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Internally `\c@counterA` holds the value and `\thecounterA` is the representation. On LaTeX level `\c@counterA` shouldn't be used.

Comment: Why the `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @Herbert He is demonstrating that the macro `\counterA` does not work if renewed. You need to use `\value{counterA}`. Quite an important detail Herbert! Thanks.

Comment: @Herbert But why does `\ifx \somecounter>2 \else \fi` work?

Comment: no, it doesn't work: `\newcount\foo \foo=0     foo is \ifx\the\foo<2 less \else greater than \fi 2`  `\ifx` compares `\the` and `\foo`: And in your case it compares `\somecounter` with `>`

Answer (score 10):

Use `\ifnum` instead of `\ifx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterA}{2}
\setcounter{counterB}{2}

\newcommand\maccommand{%
    \ifnum\the\value{counterA}=\the\value{counterB}
        Just so you know, counterA (= \the\value{counterA}) holds the same value as counterB (= \the\value{counterB}).%
    \else 
        Sorry, but the counterA (= \the\value{counterA}) is not equal to counterB (= \the\value{counterB}).%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
\maccommand

\stepcounter{counterA}
\maccommand
\end{document}
```

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Good point, I'll add that.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Although the previous solution was good in case you want to add arguments.

Comment: You answered the question correctly, I would just like to clear some things up. If you have time, maybe have a look at the edits to my question.

Comment: @macmadness86 What about the edit?

Comment: @macmadness86 I think your edits belong on a new question though.

Comment: You should not use `\thecounterA` for such tests: you want to use the counter's *value* as opposed to its representation. Think to the case `\newcounter{counterA}[section]` and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Now you have a very wrong `%`. Try adding `1000` before `Just`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks again! What happened there?

Comment: `\ifnum\the\value{counterA}=\the\value{counterB}1000Just` becomes `\ifnum2=21000Just`

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly do, in plain TeX,

```
\newcount\counterA

\counterA=2

\ifx\counterA>2 
  Just so you know, counterA is greater to than 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
\fi
```

but this will compare the token `\counterA` with the token `>` and find they've different meanings, so everything up to `\else` will be gobbled and you'll get

> Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.

But if you now try adding

```
\counterA=1000

\ifx\counterA>2 
  Just so you know, counterA is greater to than 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
\fi
}
```

you'll get exactly the same.

For numeric tests you have to use `\ifnum`; the code

```
\newcount\counterA

\counterA=2

\ifnum\counterA>2 
  Just so you know, counterA is greater to than 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
\fi

\counterA=1000

\ifnum\counterA>2 
  Just so you know, counterA is greater to than 2.
\else 
  Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
\fi
}
```

will produce

> Just so you know, counterA is not greater than 2.
>   Just so you know, counterA is greater than 2.

The conditional `\ifx` compares the *meaning* of the two tokens that follow, without doing any expansion on them.

<sub>If the first or second token after `\ifx` is either `\else` or `\fi`, TeX considers the code to be an incomplete conditionals and adds one or two “frozen `\relax`” tokens, as need be.</sub>

Note, conversely, that `\ifnum` performs expansion, because it needs to find a `<number>` followed by a `<relation>` (one among `=`<sub>12</sub>, `<`<sub>12</sub> or `>`<sub>12</sub>) and another `<number>`.

Since in LaTeX the instruction `\newcounter{counterA}` performs also `\newcount\c@counterA` and the macro `\value` is defined by

```
% latex.ltx, line 2084:
\def\value#1{\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

Therefore, doing

```
\ifnum\value{counterA}>\value{counterB}
```

will provide the appropriate tokens for the test. Hence your code could be

```
\newcommand\maccommand{%
  \ifnum\value{counterA}=\value{counterB}% <--- don't forget this!
    Just so you know, counterA (= \thecounterA) holds the same value as counterB (= \thecounterB).%
  \else 
    Sorry, but the counterA (= \thecounterA) is not equal to counterB (= \thecounterB).%
  \fi
}
```

Note that `\the\value{counterA}` is not needed. However, a `%` after `\value{counterB}` is needed, because `\c@counterB` is a counter register, so TeX doesn't look for an `<optional space>` after it. This `<optional space>` would be looked for and gobbled in case you use `\the\value{counterB}`, but this method is conceptually wrong.

In the body of the macro I used `\thecounterA` and `\thecounterB`, which expand to the current representation of the counter's values (default, decimal number). It would be wrong to use `\thecounterA` in the numeric test for `\ifnum`.