# LaTeX: How can I change colors according to chapter number in Memoir?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, memoir, loops

I would like to change the color of some page elements (rules, headers...) depending on the chapter number, like first chapter, color blue, second, color green... and cycle after four chapters; this in order to match colors with some company's logos

I tried to create some counters and increment them for each new chapter by redefining the command \memendofchapterhook from memoir class - which executes after each new chapter, at the end of \chapter.

Nevertheless, it doesn't work as the color doesn't follow the changes in the counters

Here's my tex file, Counters are defined in the preamble, the color of header's rule is defined in the preamble also, in the headers section

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Example of the Memoir class, an alternative to the default LaTeX classes such as article and book, with many added features built into the class itself.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,book,openright,notitlepage %,draft %,draft  %si draft, pas d'images ds le doc final
            ]{memoir} % for a short document

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %set output encoding 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%CHANGEMENT DE LANGUE
\usepackage[french]{babel} %change la langue pour le français

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
% Set up the paper to be as close as possible to both A4 & letter:
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*} % letter = 11in tall; a4 = 210mm wide modifié A4 pur
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\setlxvchars \setxlvchars[\normalfont]%censé régler la largeur du bloc de caractères pour un nbre optimum de lettres /lignes en fonction de la police
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.618} % we want to the text block to have golden proportionals
\setbinding{20pt} %ajoute un espace pour la reliure (cette valeur est soustraite de la largeur théorique de la page)
\setulmargins{50pt}{*}{*} % 50pt upper margins
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.618} % golden ratio again for left/right margins
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1.618}

\checkandfixthelayout 
% This is from memman.pdf



%%% COULEURS & LOGO
\definecolor{logo_purple}{RGB}{109,20,71}%Définit la couleur POURPRE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_blue}{RGB}{15,115,159}%Définit la couleur BLEUE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_green}{RGB}{129,166,42}%Définit la couleur VERTE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_orange}{RGB}{238,128,15}%Définit la couleur ORANGE du logo SPMS

\newcommand{\logoColor}{\color{logo_blue}}

\newcounter{logoUn}\setcounter{logoUn}{0}
\newcounter{logoDeux}\setcounter{logoDeux}{1}
\newcounter{logoTrois}\setcounter{logoTrois}{2}
\newcounter{logoQuatre}\setcounter{logoQuatre}{3}
\renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{%%redéfinition d'une commande (vide) de memoir qui s'exécute *après* la commande \chapter 
    \stepcounter{logoUn}
    \stepcounter{logoDeux}
    \stepcounter{logoTrois}
    \stepcounter{logoQuatre}
    \ifnum \thelogoUn=4 {cas1 \renewcommand{\logoColor}{\color{logo_blue}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoDeux=4 {cas2 \renewcommand{\logoColor}{\color{logo_green}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoTrois = 4 {cas3 \renewcommand{\logoColor}{\color{logo_orange}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoQuatre = 4 {cas4} \fi
    %   \else {cas autre}
    %\fi     

} 

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS

\copypagestyle{my_page_style}{ruled} %définit un style local modifiable basé sur "ruled"
    \makeheadfootruleprefix{my_page_style}{\logoColor}{} %définit la couleur du trait entre l'en-tête et le texte et entre le texte et le pied de page (N/A pour le style "ruled")
    \makeheadrule{my_page_style}{\textwidth}{4pt} %style de page, longueur de la règle, épaisseur (\normalrulethickness = 0.4pt)





%applique ce style au document
\pagestyle{my_page_style} % try also: empty , plain , headings , ruled , Ruled , companion 


%%% CHAPTERS
\chapterstyle{bianchi} % try also: default , section , hangnum , companion , article, demo, verville, wilsondob, ger, komalike,dash, culver, crosshead, chappell, brotherton,bringhurst, 

%% END Memoir customization



%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}


\mainmatter %correspond au contenu principal, les pages sont numérotées en chiffres arabes, la numérotation reprend au début. 
        %Attention, les appendices font partie du contenu principal!


\chapter{test}\thispagestyle{my_page_style}
\thelogoUn
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

\par


\chapter{Description}
Valeur : \thelogoUn

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

Donec faucibus, elit non sagittis feugiat, justo erat luctus eros, nec hendrerit nulla mi non nisi. Phasellus bibendum, libero a suscipit efficitur, diam ligula congue nunc, feugiat finibus eros urna nec nisi. Vestibulum arcu mi, tempor ac lorem in, eleifend facilisis lacus. Mauris ut velit at leo pellentesque placerat. Donec ut ipsum a elit elementum viverra. Phasellus blandit, tortor et tincidunt congue, nibh ipsum convallis elit, ac rutrum dui odio in quam. Morbi eu lorem sed erat dignissim lacinia. Aliquam rhoncus et tellus et dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nam ullamcorper dapibus dignissim. Nullam laoreet semper ipsum, ut dapibus ligula vehicula a. Ut nisi massa, iaculis a magna mattis, malesuada facilisis elit. Ut vestibulum dolor ac interdum blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porta augue risus, ut tristique dolor commodo lobortis. Donec sagittis at diam quis sodales. Praesent maximus sollicitudin felis, et fermentum massa pretium non.

\chapter{Dummy chapter}
\section{Dummy section}
Nam ullamcorper dapibus dignissim. Nullam laoreet semper ipsum, ut dapibus ligula vehicula a. Ut nisi massa, iaculis a magna mattis, malesuada facilisis elit. Ut vestibulum dolor ac interdum blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porta augue risus, ut tristique dolor commodo lobortis. Donec sagittis at diam quis sodales. Praesent maximus sollicitudin felis, et fermentum massa pretium non. 

\end{document}
```

I'm not very proficient in latex or tex, so please don't hesitate to dumb down your answers...
Thanks

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287267/how-can-i-test-the-value-of-two-counters (especially the answers).

Comment: @Marijn: the "counter" part of the solution I tried to implement are working in the way described in the thread you mention. I have tested them and I get an actual increment of each counter as the chapters go by. Nevertheless, the color value is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was in the redefinition of `\memendofchapterhook`.  I made two types of changes.  First I added `\relax` after the `\ifnum` test inputs, but more importantly, I used `\gdef`\ rather than `\renewcommand` to redefine `\logoColor`.

```
\renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{%%redéfinition d'une commande (vide) de memoir qui s'exécute *après* la commande \chapter 
    \stepcounter{logoUn}
    \stepcounter{logoDeux}
    \stepcounter{logoTrois}
    \stepcounter{logoQuatre}
    \ifnum \thelogoUn=4\relax {cas1 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_blue}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoDeux=4\relax {cas2 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_green}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoTrois = 4\relax {cas3 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_orange}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoQuatre = 4\relax {cas4} \fi
    %   \else {cas autre}
    %\fi     

}
```

The revised MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Example of the Memoir class, an alternative to the default LaTeX classes such as article and book, with many added features built into the class itself.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,book,openright,notitlepage %,draft %,draft  %si draft, pas d'images ds le doc final
            ]{memoir} % for a short document

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %set output encoding 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%%CHANGEMENT DE LANGUE
\usepackage[french]{babel} %change la langue pour le français

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
% Set up the paper to be as close as possible to both A4 & letter:
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*} % letter = 11in tall; a4 = 210mm wide modifié A4 pur
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\setlxvchars \setxlvchars[\normalfont]%censé régler la largeur du bloc de caractères pour un nbre optimum de lettres /lignes en fonction de la police
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.618} % we want to the text block to have golden proportionals
\setbinding{20pt} %ajoute un espace pour la reliure (cette valeur est soustraite de la largeur théorique de la page)
\setulmargins{50pt}{*}{*} % 50pt upper margins
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.618} % golden ratio again for left/right margins
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1.618}

\checkandfixthelayout 
% This is from memman.pdf



%%% COULEURS & LOGO
\definecolor{logo_purple}{RGB}{109,20,71}%Définit la couleur POURPRE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_blue}{RGB}{15,115,159}%Définit la couleur BLEUE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_green}{RGB}{129,166,42}%Définit la couleur VERTE du logo SPMS
\definecolor{logo_orange}{RGB}{238,128,15}%Définit la couleur ORANGE du logo SPMS

\newcommand{\logoColor}{\color{logo_blue}}

\newcounter{logoUn}\setcounter{logoUn}{0}
\newcounter{logoDeux}\setcounter{logoDeux}{1}
\newcounter{logoTrois}\setcounter{logoTrois}{2}
\newcounter{logoQuatre}\setcounter{logoQuatre}{3}
\renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{%%redéfinition d'une commande (vide) de memoir qui s'exécute *après* la commande \chapter 
    \stepcounter{logoUn}
    \stepcounter{logoDeux}
    \stepcounter{logoTrois}
    \stepcounter{logoQuatre}
    \ifnum \thelogoUn=4\relax {cas1 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_blue}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoDeux=4\relax {cas2 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_green}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoTrois = 4\relax {cas3 \gdef\logoColor{\color{logo_orange}}\pagestyle{my_page_style}} \fi
    \ifnum \thelogoQuatre = 4\relax {cas4} \fi
    %   \else {cas autre}
    %\fi     

} 

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS

\copypagestyle{my_page_style}{ruled} %définit un style local modifiable basé sur "ruled"
    \makeheadfootruleprefix{my_page_style}{\logoColor}{} %définit la couleur du trait entre l'en-tête et le texte et entre le texte et le pied de page (N/A pour le style "ruled")
    \makeheadrule{my_page_style}{\textwidth}{4pt} %style de page, longueur de la règle, épaisseur (\normalrulethickness = 0.4pt)





%applique ce style au document
\pagestyle{my_page_style} % try also: empty , plain , headings , ruled , Ruled , companion 


%%% CHAPTERS
\chapterstyle{bianchi} % try also: default , section , hangnum , companion , article, demo, verville, wilsondob, ger, komalike,dash, culver, crosshead, chappell, brotherton,bringhurst, 

%% END Memoir customization



%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}


\mainmatter %correspond au contenu principal, les pages sont numérotées en chiffres arabes, la numérotation reprend au début. 
        %Attention, les appendices font partie du contenu principal!


\chapter{test}\thispagestyle{my_page_style}
\thelogoUn
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

\par


\chapter{Description}
Valeur : \thelogoUn

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vulputate mauris at nisl tristique, eu pharetra turpis suscipit. Suspendisse sed pellentesque ligula. Maecenas pulvinar mi velit, at lobortis velit faucibus sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut rhoncus eros maximus nibh semper varius. Proin mollis risus augue, sit amet porta metus aliquet et. Cras sit amet scelerisque lorem. Vivamus rhoncus tincidunt lacus, non malesuada enim sollicitudin non. Sed consectetur ipsum eget bibendum vehicula. Phasellus in laoreet purus, accumsan convallis ex. Ut sed semper ipsum. Nam vitae eros a tortor iaculis varius. Ut eu sem sed arcu venenatis pulvinar. Curabitur augue arcu, tempus in suscipit sit amet, auctor a nisi. In laoreet ornare lacus, in iaculis odio tincidunt ac.

Donec faucibus, elit non sagittis feugiat, justo erat luctus eros, nec hendrerit nulla mi non nisi. Phasellus bibendum, libero a suscipit efficitur, diam ligula congue nunc, feugiat finibus eros urna nec nisi. Vestibulum arcu mi, tempor ac lorem in, eleifend facilisis lacus. Mauris ut velit at leo pellentesque placerat. Donec ut ipsum a elit elementum viverra. Phasellus blandit, tortor et tincidunt congue, nibh ipsum convallis elit, ac rutrum dui odio in quam. Morbi eu lorem sed erat dignissim lacinia. Aliquam rhoncus et tellus et dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nam ullamcorper dapibus dignissim. Nullam laoreet semper ipsum, ut dapibus ligula vehicula a. Ut nisi massa, iaculis a magna mattis, malesuada facilisis elit. Ut vestibulum dolor ac interdum blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porta augue risus, ut tristique dolor commodo lobortis. Donec sagittis at diam quis sodales. Praesent maximus sollicitudin felis, et fermentum massa pretium non.

\chapter{Dummy chapter}
\section{Dummy section}
Nam ullamcorper dapibus dignissim. Nullam laoreet semper ipsum, ut dapibus ligula vehicula a. Ut nisi massa, iaculis a magna mattis, malesuada facilisis elit. Ut vestibulum dolor ac interdum blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse porta augue risus, ut tristique dolor commodo lobortis. Donec sagittis at diam quis sodales. Praesent maximus sollicitudin felis, et fermentum massa pretium non. 

\clearpage
Finis!

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]